# How can I filter a file upload by type with Perl (e.g. .png, .bmp, .jpg)

Tags: html, perl, forms, webforms, fastcgi

I'm trying to filter uploads by file type. I'm using the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT  

use strict;  
use CGI;  
use CGI::Carp qw ( fatalsToBrowser );  
use File::Basename;  

my $query = new CGI;  
my $filename = $query->param("photo");  
my $user_username = $query->param("example_text");  

$CGI::POST_MAX = 1024 * 5000;  
my $safe_filename_characters = "a-zA-Z0-9_.-";  
my $upload_dir = "/" . $user_username;  

if ( !$filename )  
{  
 print $query->header ( );  
 print "There was a problem uploading your photo (try a smaller file).";  
 exit;  
}  

my ( $name, $path, $extension ) = fileparse ( $filename, '\..*' );  
$filename = "user_pro_pic" . ".png";  
$filename =~ tr/ /_/;  
$filename =~ s/[^$safe_filename_characters]//g;  

if ( $filename =~ /^([$safe_filename_characters]+)$/ )  
{  
 $filename = $1;  
}  
else  
{  
 die "Filename contains invalid characters";  
}  

my $upload_filehandle = $query->upload("photo");  

open ( UPLOADFILE, ">$upload_dir/$filename" ) or die "$!";  
binmode UPLOADFILE;  

while ( <$upload_filehandle> )  
{  
 print UPLOADFILE;  
}  

close UPLOADFILE;  

print $query->header ( );   
print "$user_username";
print "<script> location.href='http://google.com/' </script>";
```